# CakePHP show variable value

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I'm using CakePHP (v3.0) and I want to show on screen the variable value.
I have tried to use `print_r()` function, but not always runs..

Whats would be the best option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CakePHP comes with `pr()` function you can use that

[Documentation link](http://api.cakephp.org/3.0/function-pr.html)

Comment: just try `pr($numbers); die;`

Comment: I have tried with this example and don't show nothing: $numbers = [1,2,3]; pr($numbers);

Comment: try `$numbers = [1,2,3]; pr($numbers);die("text");` did that work ?

Comment: Now yes, I forgot die() function.. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I always use cake's `debug()` function, but you should consider using `DebugKit` for debugging your app.

[DebugKit](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/debug-kit.html#debug-kit)